# search custom environment in RStudio panel

Tags: rstudio

I have defined a new environment:

```
myEnv <- new.env()
```

and defined new variables in this environments:

```
myEnv$data <- data1
```

The way I have set my options in RStudio, I see all defined variables in the right-upper panel in the tab "Environment". Above this panel, there is a drop-down menu which by default is set to "Global Environment". I was expecting to find the newly created environment `myEnv` in this drop-down menu, but it isn't. `myEnv$data` also isn't in the list of the global environment where I find `data1` for instance.

Is there a way to view these objects in the panel? Seems like a basic question, but I could find anything, so sorry if duplicate.

RStudio Version 1.0.143

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it to appear in that panel by attaching it to the search list:

```
myEnv <- new.env()
myEnv$data <- 1:10
attach(myEnv)
```

and then looking through the drop down list.  This also means that the `data` element of it will hide the `data()` function:

```
data
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Because `attach()` has such potential side effects, it's generally a good idea to avoid it.

So what can you do?  One thing is to just click on the `myEnv` entry in the global environment.  It will be expanded in a panel in the source pane (on the top left on my system, yours may be elsewhere) showing the contents.  Not quite the same format as the `Environment` tab, but good enough to see what's going on.

Comment: I've tried the view objects of `myEnv` according to your suggestion. I can find `myEnv` under "Values" as an Environment object. If I hover my mouse over it, it shows a hand but nothing happens when I click.

Comment: As far as I understand, using `attach()` is not recommended because its easy to confuse object of the same name from different environments. Is there a problem using it if I always reference the environment (`myEnv$data` instead of `data`)?

Comment: No, accessing it explicitly is fine.  Another way is to use `with(myEnv, <some expression involving data>)`.  This is a little risky (`data` will hide the standard object), but it only lasts for one expression, so it's safer than `attach(myEnv)`.  Regarding the click to display:  I'm using version 1.1.383, so I guess this is a new feature.